# Inkscape Corners / Fillet

Tags: inkscape, rounding

I tried to use the path effect 'Corners (Fillet/Chamfer)' to round the corners of a shape. Unfortunately, this is not working on all corners. Some do not round the exact radius that is set.
I made a circle object with the same radius and there is a gap.

Radius of fillet not correct:
[image: Radius of fillet not correct]

Comment: You may have better luck on[Graphics Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you try using the "Force arc" method in the Corners (Fillet/Chamfer) LPE effects panel, rather than the default "Auto" setting.

Here's an example

[image]

With the "Force arc" setting selected, swap to Edit Paths by Nodes tool <kbd>N</kbd> and when you click drag the corner controls, the rounded corner will be constrained to a proper arc.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).